# Screen densities and sizes on android (Diff between large/x-large.. // hdpi, xhdpi...)

Tags: android, size, screen, resolution, scaling

I've read so much about these things already, so many threads, but there still some things that I don't understand about how to, as a both developer and a designer, avoid problems with different sized screens.
So my question is mainly: What is the difference between putting drawables into mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi folders as opposed to normal,large,xlarge folders? Should I do both?
I want drawables to act like this: If it takes 50% of the width of the screen on a smartphone, it should take 50% of the screen on a tablet. That's where I'm also confused - Both my phone and tablet are 1920x1080 and both fall into the xhdpi bucket (I believe), but their physical screen sizes are very much different.

Now I save drawables according to the mdpi, hdpi... ratios. Therefore I get results like this on the phone:
[image]

When I just out of curiosity created folders for drawables large and xlarge (I didn't know the ratios), I get this, which is closer to what I'm aiming for (but is obviously too big):
[image]

But what's the point of using the xhdpi (etc) buckets? Am I understanding this completely wrong? Someone please enlighten me. I hope this question makes sense. My point is - I want the scales of text and pictures to fill about as much of the screen on a tablet as on a smartphone.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We developers just create drawbles for mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi because screen resolution of devices maybe different. While in the case of the normal, large, xlarge folders it is used for the case of screen sizes.We Use This configuration qualifiers (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi) because for example for low budget phone, resolution maybe less and will show 48px drawable bigger while high end devices will show it smaller. That's why we create drawables for different resolutions of phones varying from 42(maybe) to 192 px.Similarly normal,large,xlarge folders are used in respect with screen size.
If you want to compress app size, you may use vector drawables. They are just created for one time and look consistent on every time.For Custom icons, export it to .svg or .psd format and create it as vector drawable through android studio.

**Edit :** I usually create my logo on Photoshop and android studio efficiently exports it to vector drawable.
xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp.
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp.
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp.
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp.
Vector drawables are put in drawables folder. There is one more advantage of using vector drawables that is one May animate it.

**Note :** Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), these size groups small, normal, large,xlarge folders are deprecated in favor of a new technique for managing screen sizes based on the available screen width. If you're developing for Android 3.2 and greater use mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi folders.

The configuration qualifiers (described in detail below) that you can use for density-specific resources are ldpi (low), mdpi (medium), hdpi (high), xhdpi extra-high), xxhdpi (extra-extra-high), and xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high).
Screen Density of devices

A set of six generalized densities:
ldpi (low) ~120dpi
mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
hdpi (high) ~240dpi
xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi

Images Sizes as per folders.
36x36 (0.75x) for low-density
48x48 (1.0x baseline) for medium-density
72x72 (1.5x) for high-density
96x96 (2.0x) for extra-high-density
144x144 (3.0x) for extra-extra-high-density
192x192 (4.0x) for extra-extra-extra-high-density.  Hope this will help.You ask me more about this in detail in comments.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. So what about graphics that cannot be done as vector drawables? For example the logo? Which folders / sizes should I save it to, so that it looks consistent? Also, what is the ratios between normal, large and xlarge and small? Should I include it in those + hdpi xhdpi etc?

Comment: Okay but I'd like to know more about the non-vector, png images. What do I do and which folders / sizes do I include for them to show well on all kinds of screens?

Comment: Thanks For Choosing My Answer Helpful And Correct @Samuel Bañas

Comment: Thanks. The difference is now clear to me. 
So I am using folders for mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi with properly scaled images to the ratios: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pghl.jpg as you can see in this image, on the left, this is the result of it on a tablet. The images are too small. However, they look the right size on a smartphone: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xg5ng.jpg 
What can I do to fix that?

Also, should I be using the mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi for dimens.xml as well?

Comment: I think you should create different layout for tablets.See this link I learnt about same from this link : https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: There are many types of configuration like landscape ,screen resolution. Even you can use another feature fragments

Comment: I think have you given image dimensions as per above answer i.e. 36x36 ...192x192px